# How to turn off chat in Minecraft on mobile device

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios

I read that you can go into multi player settings and scroll to turn off chat but I don’t see this option in the mobile app version on my sons ipod/iPhone. Is there a way to turn off chat on the iPod or iPhone app version in Minecraft?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to turn off chat but if you click the chat button in the top right corner there is a mute button turn it on. Hope this helped